# Incremetal backups of directories with a batch/shell script

Tags: shell, batch-file, backup

I'm trying to create a script that will automatically backup a complete directory tree. I also want it to work for incremental backups. Basically, it wil work like this:

- If file is in both source and destination and they are different, source file will be copied

  If file is in both source and destination and they are the same, nothing will be copied

  If file is only in the source, source file will be copied

  If file is only in the destination, destination file will be deleted.

I'm still new to shell scripting and I'm not sure how I could implement this. Any ideas? Windows batch scripts would be better, but shell scripts that run on Cygwin are also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows batch scripting [xcopy](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) (native to windows) or [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) (a free download in windows) both work extremely well.

An example `xcopy` script (in a `.bat` file):

```
@echo off
:: /L = list only.
:: /v=Verify, /y=No prompting /s=subdirs /z=Network mode (supports bad)
:: /i=Tells xcopy dest is folder /f=Display names /d=Copy only changed

echo Backing up projects...
xcopy e:\projects h:\projects /V /Y /S /Z /I /F /D
```

It will even support orphaned files (if you delete something from your source you no longer need a copy in the backup).  `Xcopy` is typically fine for your needs until you deal with sync between NTFS and Fat32 file systems - the later only has a 2 second resolution and problems with daily savings time so you occasionally run into issues: (a) on time change day you might not get a backup of a changed file - depends on change-regularity of course or you might get a backup of all files even though none have changed (b) because of time resolution some files may backup even though they haven't changed.

Comment: Thanks!! Robocopy did the trick, I used
robocopy <source> <dest> /mir

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at rsync tool - it was designed to minimize traffic during files synchronization.

Also, probably "cp" with "-u" argument will be useful:

> -u, --update
>
> ```
> copy only when the SOURCE file is newer than the destination file or when the destination file is missing
> ```

Comment: I'd rather not use other tools. I've used Syncback and rsync in the past and they're great, but I want to know if there's a way to do it with just a regular batch script.

Comment: @limitedmage: rsync is no more of an "other tool" than robocopy is.

Comment: But Robocopy is included with Windows, rsync isn't. I don't have to install anything extra to do the backups.